# Postgresql select from 2 tables. Joins?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 2 tables that look like this:

```
    Table "public.phone_lists"
  Column  |       Type        |                             Modifiers                              
----------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 id       | integer           | not null default nextval(('"phone_lists_id_seq"'::text)::regclass)
 list_id  | integer           | not null
 sequence | integer           | not null
 phone    | character varying | 
 name     | character varying |
```

and

```
Table "public.email_lists"
 Column  |       Type        |                             Modifiers                              
---------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 id      | integer           | not null default nextval(('"email_lists_id_seq"'::text)::regclass)
 list_id | integer           | not null
 email   | character varying |
```

I'm trying to get the list_id, phone, and emails out of the tables in one table. I'm looking for an output like:

```
list_id |    phone    |             email              
---------+-------------+--------------------------------
       0 |             | jqeron@wqwerweper.com
       0 |             | qwerox@wqwekeeper.com
       0 |             | erreon@fdfdeper.com
       0 |             | sfar@weasdfer.com
       0 |             | rawq@gdfefdgheper.com
       1 | 15555555555 | 
       1 | 15555551806 | 
       1 | 15555555508 | 
       1 | 15055555506 | 
       1 | 15055555558 | 
       1 |             | rfoasdfx@wefdaser.com
       1 |             | radfy@wfdfder.com
```

I've come up with

```
select pl.list_id, pl.phone, el.email from phone_lists as pl left join email_lists as el using (list_id);
```

but thats not quite right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain why some emails don't have a list_id?

Comment: You provided output but not input, please provide one. Also, `list_id` is `NOT NULL` in both tables, but you expect `NULLs ` in your output.

Comment: Those should and do have a list_id of 0, but the formatting messed up. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  list_id, phone, email
FROM    (
        SELECT  list_id, NULL AS phone, email, 1 AS set_id
        FROM    email_lists
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  list_id, phone, NULL AS email, 2 AS set_id
        FROM    phone_lists
        ) q
ORDER BY
        list_id, set_id
```

Comment: could you be so kind as to explain how this works, and it does work. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel: `UNION ALL` is a multiset addition operation, it concatenates two recordsets together. Then the result of the concatenation is ordered by list id, then by source